# How to aggregate in preload

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I have 3 tables **borrower**, **avatar** and **loan**

Borrower -> has_one avatar

Borrower -> has_many loan

**Loan Controller**

```
def list_borrowers do

query =
  from(
    p in Borrower,
    select: p,
    preload: [:avatar],
    preload: [:loan] # I WANT TO AGGREGATE THIS USING COUNT
  )

IO.inspect(Repo.all(query))end
```

This is working properly my problem is I don't know how to aggregate the **loan**.

I just want to know the number of all the loans of that borrower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unaware of any possible way to `preload` the aggregate, but you might declare [virtual field](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3) instead and include it into your query as:

```
from p in Borrower,
  join: l in Loan,
  on: p.id == l.borrower_id,
  select: %{p | loan_count: count(l.id)}, # virtual field
  preload: [:avatar]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ill try your answer.

Comment: I tested and your answer and its working, BUT if the borrower has no  **LOAN** its not showing on the list. How to fix it ??

Comment: Use `left join` then. That’s a raw SQL query underneath, construct the dataset you want to show.